# Expose Swift Package as part of Another Swift Package

Tags: swift, package, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I have a set of Swift Packages that I'm writing (ex: [CUIExpandableButton](https://github.com/robhasacamera/CUIExpandableButton)), that I'd like to roll up into another Swift Package called CrystalUI. The overall goal is to write a set of packages that get bundled into a single package. However, I want to make it so people can just have one import

```
import CrystalUI
```

instead of a series of import statements

```
import CrystalUI
import CUIExpandableButton
import PreviewKit
...
```

Is it possible to re-expose an existing library as part of the parent library?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `@_exported` Is what I was looking for. Found this [article](https://forums.swift.org/t/what-does-exported-import-do/35869/5) that explains it. It's an unsupported method but it's also used in [Alamofire](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/-/blob/Source/Alamofire.swift?L28) so I think it's safe.